# If I'm using a MIT library in my project, can I license my project under GPLv3 license?

Tags: licensing, mit, gpl-3, license-compatibility

If I'm using a MIT library in my project, can I license my project under GPLv3 license? And which libraries Im allow to use if I want to license my project under GPL v3?

Comment: For example, I want to use the three.js MIT licensed library in my project and I want to license my project under GPLv3, Im I allowed to do it ? And what other libraries Im I allowed to use ?

Answer (score 4):

The MIT License is compatible with GPLv3. You can find a simple graph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility#/media/File:Floss-license-slide-image.svg).

The way how GPL compatibility is determined can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatDoesCompatMean). And there is even a [list of FSF with compatible licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html)

Comment: Indeed. You should go to the section titled "GPL-Compatible Free Software Licenses" and look there. These licenses will have a green bar to the left of them.